# PHP Get unique array from foreach loop

Tags: php, foreach

I have two tables (category and fields), where one field can be assigned to multiple categories like this

```
name       |   category_ids
color      |   1,2
size       |   1,3
```

I am trying to get fields assigned for given gategories like this

```
foreach($category_ids as $category_id){
    $fields = $this->model->getFields($category_id);
        foreach ($fields as $field) {
        echo $field->name;
        }
}
```

This output will give me values including duplicates. How can I remove duplicates here. Please help 
EDIT:
For example `$category_ids` are 1,2 then output I am getting is `color,color,size` 
But I want the output be like `color,size`

Comment: what is there in `$category_ids`? what output is coming with your current code? what is your expected outcome? paste there and you will get solution. thanks

Comment: Add to your question the desired output from the example input you showed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store all the fetched values in array and then you can use array_unique function to remove duplicate values.

```
$fieldsArray = [];
foreach($category_ids as $category_id){
    $fields = $this->model->getFields($category_id);
        foreach ($fields as $field) {
           $fieldsArray[] = $field->name;
        }
}
$fieldsArray = array_unique($fieldsArray);
```

Comment: This is exactly I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
$existing = array();
foreach($category_ids as $category_id) { 

    $fields = $this->model->getFields($category_id);
    foreach ($fields as $field) { 
        if (!in_array($field->name, $existing)) { 
            $existing[] = $field->name;
            echo $field->name;
        }
    }
}
```

But I'd like to suggest you to normalize the db. It'll be the best solution, I think.